# Adding content to active element but removing it if element is not active?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu where clicking on it adds an `.active` class and some content within the list item  (a paragraph). I have figured out how to add the active class but am not sure how to remove the add content once the list item no longer has the active class.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(this).append(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                return "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

This adds the desired paragraph when `.active` has been added but does not remove it once the list item no longer has this class. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do a `hasClass("active")` check - it'll always be true, you just added the class in the line above.. and you never remove the `p` from the other non-active containers.

Answer (score 2):

You never remove the `p` from any other `li` - and you also don't need the redundant checks:

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    //Remove active class and remove p
    $("ul li.active").removeClass("active").each(function() {
        $(this).find("p").remove(); //remove old p
    });

    //Add active class to element clicked and append
    $(this).addClass("active").append(function(){
        return "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ufx60ry/

Comment: Thank you this works. But why are you removing class before the class has been added? Should the second piece of code come first?

Comment: @Jason -- Nope - that first line removes the active class from any other `li` that has it - the second line then adds the active class to the element you clicked.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: I'm a novice no need to be rude

Answer (score 0):

Not really ideal, but with your current setup, you can easily do this:

```js
    $("ul li").on('click', function(e){
        if($(this).is(':not(.active)')) {
            $(this).addClass("active").append(function(){
                return "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
            }).siblings().removeClass("active").find('p').remove();
        }
        
        // for demo purposes
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2em;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #C55;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li.active a {
    color: #55C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus">Aliquam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare">Morbi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus">Praesent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque fermentum dolor">Pellentesque</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't remove the paragraphs.

Comment: @Jason Sorry about that.  I really should test my code :P